# Code scope in evm

Tags: solidity, evm, opcode

Short question, how is code scope defined/determined by the compiler when looking at EVM opcodes (or rather bitcode)? Is it simply by looking out for jump calls or return statements? Or does it define scope from jump destinations to returning calls?

Comment: returns can be optimized out by the optimizer, so....

Comment: I suggest to look into disassembling techniques, it is completely different science